# Особенности работы приложений на разных устройствах Андроид

Tags: android

Добрый день!
Выложил в маркет приложение, которое тестировалось на все возможных эмуляторах + реальных устройствах. Все работает отлично. Однако пользователи пишут (конкретно с htc desire 600 dual SIM и Galaxy Note II (t03g)) о том, что вылетает ошибка на месте кода где я применял заполнение jsonArray через AsyncTask...

Что это может быть за глюк? 
Ума не приложу... андроид такой разный андроид...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем гадать? Добавь функционал чтоб приложение слало логи разработчику на мыло после краша.
`Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();` например.

Answer (score 1):

При отправке отзыва о падении приложения прикрепляется стектрейс, который отображается в консоли разработчика в Google Play.
Так же можно использовать библиотеку [Acra](https://github.com/ACRA/acra) или аналогичные для прямой отправки

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду вкладку "Сбои и ANR"? Там 0 везде... может еще не обновилось.

Comment: Ошибок в коде нет, в том-то и дело (я так думаю, потому что работает на других устройствах нормально).... в асинктаске забираются данные с сервера в json, а в onPostExecute (где и срабатывает catch-ошибка) идет заполнение данных экземпляров класса через json.getString ... и это Работает! Но почему-то не у всех... вот беда)

Comment: Там не только это, если пользователь нажимает "отменить" вместо "отправить отчет", то ничего толкового не появится на той вкладке.

Comment: @Chekist Acra позволяет отправить лог, не спрашивая у пользователя.

Comment: А вы попробуйте, во время работы асинк теск, покрутить девайс, выключить , позвонить, закрыть. да вообще все что угодно, и смотрите реакцию. возможно что то упустили. да и для логов нынче есть  - crashlytics, вроде вырос из акры, интеграция (в eclipse) в один клик, и вроде как бесплатный

Answer (score 0):

Я смотрю либо в google analytics - закладку Behavior -Crashes and Exceptions
мне нравится там статистика и по версиям приложения, внутри версий описания ошибок. Можно определить какие ошибки критичные , у 5% пользователей, или случайные, у 1,2х пользователей за месяц случилось :)
Либо в консоли разработчика конечно Сбои и Anr - там тексты ошибок есть, смотришь в какой строке ошибка, лезешь в код, думаешь почему.
 Иногда бывают вообще мистические вещи...
 Например была переменная условно int a=1; в процессе работы могла принимать значение 2, сохранялась в преференсе,  в следующие раз из Preference читалась. Я наивный, думал что ну значит она либо 2 либо 1... но не тут то было... у пары пользователей из 1000 вылетал краш при делении на 0 :)

Comment: Вот и тоже гадаю, мистика какая-то... у 99 работает, у 1 - нет... причем этот "нет" ставит "3" в маркете :-E